# Which software can I use to make this type of video?

Tags: video, video-editing

I am searching for software which help to create the videos / animations like given below references:

1. *[HOW TO GET RICH HINDI RICH DAD POOR DAD, Deepak Sharma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aONzP1utxuw)*
2. *[7 HABITS OF HIGHLY EFFECTIVE PEOPLE - (HINDI)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36QztlgissA)*

Kindly, guide me which softwares help to make this?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should it run on, what is your price limit, what kind of input material do you use, what features do you need … Linking videos is fine for reference – but you don't expect us to watch videos to find out what you need, do you? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to create some animations, not videos. You could do this using Adobe Animate (formerly Adobe Flash / Macromedia Flash) but these kind of softwares requires some coding skills. After you import your video and add your animations you can export it as a video. There are some examples how you could [create animations using Adobe Animate](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/create-2d-animation.html?playlist=/ccx/v1/collection/product/animate/segment/designer/explevel/beginner/applaunch/orientation/collection.ccx.js).

If you want to learn more about its coding you could search for "basics of ActionScript 3".

You could download 7 days trial of Adobe Animate using Adobe Creative Cloud: http://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/desktop-app.html